# Are "how do I build X?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

A few recent questions have asked about how a specific IoT device should be constructed, like so:

> [How could I create an LPG indicator?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/32/how-could-i-create-an-lpg-indicator)

It's almost certain that these questions will be **too broad**, but it's worth considering whether these are actually on-topic at all - are these questions really **about** IoT or are they just software and hardware design questions in disguise?

I propose that we create a canned off-topic reason for these sorts of questions; something like this would be ideal:

> Questions asking about **how an IoT device should be constructed** are off-topic at Internet of Things because they are often not related to the topic of IoT, rather they are questions regarding hardware and software design. Consider asking about **specific** design choices rather than asking *"how should I build this?"*.

As I discussed in a comment below, I think that a **lot** of software/hardware questions are beyond the scope of this site anyway:

- questions about **problems** with code are on-topic at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- questions about hardware problems when designing a circuit may be on topic at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)
- 'shopping' questions asking us to find resources or the best tools/devices/libraries to use are off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites.

There is certainly precedent on Stack Overflow and other SE sites to make certain classes of questions that are *mostly* closable anyway off-topic completely. Take, for example, the "debugging help" reason on Stack Overflow:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

These will often be 'unclear what you're asking' anyway, **but** Stack Overflow make it clear that this class of question is inappropriate by providing an off-topic reason.

The reason I chose the wording, 'Consider asking about specific design choices rather than asking "how should I build this?"' is because I would imagine there are *some* questions that can be good and on-topic for the site. Questions asking "Why should I use _____ for an internet-connected LPG indicator?" could easily form a great question, but could start out as something like the example I linked at the start of the question.

In summary:

- making "build my device" questions off-topic sends a clear signal that these aren't within the scope of the site
- although most can be closed with **too broad**, questions about software/hardware might be out of scope anyway, so explicitly calling these questions off-topic could help to define the site (although this needs more discussion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree with this approach. If I understand your proposal correctly, it sounds like questions which are initially off-topic (how do I build...?) can become on-topic by actually building them, identifying specific issues, and then reposting. That sounds like moving from *too broad* to answerable, rather than *off-topic* to answerable.

If you're going to accept specific questions on hardware/software, but not huge 'spec my whole project' questions, the distinction is one of scale, not of the questions being on- or off-topic.

Comment: Good analysis. It is about scale. We cannot be a specification service, but we can help out with specifics.

Comment: So the canned response should be ... are considered too broad ...

Comment: @SeanHoulihane That's what I would tend to do. It's still an effective means of closing a question, but it provides a means of pointing a user towards possibly, maybe rendering their question answerable by rewording to focus on specifics rather than providing a giant hand-wavey brief.

Comment: @goobering I see it in the same way as Stack Overflow's close reason "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself." Perhaps I've expressed it poorly, but I think the **majority** of software/hardware questions are off-topic (e.g. "why doesn't my hardware work?" should be off-topic in my opinion), though asking more generically about "device X" can be on-topic. I'll try to clarify the OP so you can take a look.

Comment: After [Robert Cartaino's comment](http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/questions/72/protocol-comparisions#comment148_73) on another answer, it seems pretty much official that off-topic isn't the best for things that are probably just too broad.